# React - map over actual HTML children wrapped in HoC

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a Component that renders all the children passed to it as list elements. For example:

```
// more or less the logic of my component
const ListifyChildren = (props) => {
  return <ul>{props.children.map(element => <li>{element}</li>)}</ul>
}

// example use
<ListifyChildren>
  <div>Some component</div>
  <div>Some other component</div>
</ListifyChildren>
```

Would produce

```
<ul class="listify">
  <li class="listify-list-item">Some component</li>
  <li class="listify-list-item">Some other component</li>
</ul>
```

But the problem is I want to be able to use HoC's that return a list of components and to treat those components as children of my actual list. For example:

```
const ReturnSomeStuff = () => {
 return [someArray].map(element => <div>{element}</div>
}

<ListifyChildren>
  <ReturnSomeStuff/>
</ListifyChildren>

//what I get:
<ul class="listify">
  <li class="listify-list-item">
   <div>something</div>
   <div>something</div>
   <div>something</div>
  </li>
</ul>

//what I want to get:
<ul class="listify">
   <li class="listify-list-item">something</li>
   <li class="listify-list-item">something</li>
   <li class="listify-list-item">something</li>
</ul>
```

How can I make sure that my component maps over actual html children, not the function calls passed to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer: the key is referring to child elements via [React.Children API](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildrentoarray) rather than simple props.children - it returns the list of rendered elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Fragment` to do it:  https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html

```
const ReturnSomeStuff = () => {
 return [someArray].map(element => <>{element}</>
}
```

Comment: But that doesn't solve the problem of treating maps passed to the Listify component as actual children, instead of results of mapping. So even when wrapped in React.Fragment, the Listify will only wrap in <li> the Fragment itself, not the components in it.